# GroupBy and Distinct in EntityFramework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

EF Core dose not support `GroupBy`, and i think for `Distinct` i have same problem.

so, how can i fix it?

i just get 100 first elements and then i call `Distinct()` on result List

have a better solution?

is it possible to add groupby as a extension method to EFCore?

.Net Core is not a good idea for a reporting System :/

it is trap :(

```
        query = query.Where(e => e.Goodscode.Contains(filter) || e.GoodsName.Contains(filter));
        return query.Select(e => new GoodsDTO
        {
            Name = e.GoodsName,
            Code = e.Goodscode,
            T3Code = e.T3Code,
            StockId = e.StockId
        }).Take(100).ToList().Distinct(new GoodsDTOComparer()).Take(20);
        //why we do like up: because EF7 dosent support Distinct and GroupBy yet (12-03-2017)
        //microsoft, please don't be OpenSource, because you dont care for your opensource products
```

Comment: Here's the GitHub issue link.  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2341 It looks like there's some pull requests on there.  One was updated 3 days ago

Comment: tnx, but i look for a fast solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) library for queries that not supported in ef core

example

```
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(niniSiteConnectionString))
{

    var sql = @"SELECT Name, Count(*) AS Total FROM Users
                    GROUP BY u.Name
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";

    var result = dbConnection.Query<UserDto>(sql).ToList();
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public int Total{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: tnx mohammad, can i extend EF core to support GroupBy? how can do this? Decorator pattern? can i use EF6 with .Net Core to handle this issues?